# How to use jQuery to animate HTML5 video player in response to a trigger event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

So, I'm using Jilion's Sublime's [HTML5 Video Player](http://sublimevideo.net/) on my site. And was wondering if there was a way to use some jQuery to animate my video player when certain events are triggered via the player?

For example when the play button is hit, the video player would shift into the center of the screen.

I had a dig around in the js for the player and it seems to be using things like "play", "pause", "finish" and "end" to trigger what the player does. What I was wondering is if I could that same technique as some jQuery that would say do this when "play" is hit:

```
$('#video').animate({left: '350'}, "fast");
```

I understand this is sort of a hack job, could anyone point me in the direction of how I'd go about doing something like this.

Here's an example of the play function:

```
o.play=function(a){if(a||this.ga==Dc)this.Z=0,this.coords=this.ec;else
if(this.Ga())return l;Ic(this);this.startTime=a=oa();-1==this.ga&&(this.startTime-
=this.duration*this.Z);this.ue=this.startTime+this.duration;this.rd=this.startTime;
this.Z||this.vd();this.la("play");-1==this.ga&&this.la("resume");this.ga=1;
var b=ia(this);b in Gc||(Gc[b]=this);Jc();Lc(this,a);return j};
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Ok, so this is what I've got at the moment, which seems to work.

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
v.addEventListener("playing", function() { 
$('#video').animate({left: '-90'}, "fast");
},function(){
$('#video').animate({left: '-346'}, "fast");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 video has [a number of events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Media_events) which it emits, such as play, pause, finish, and a few others. You can use jQuery's [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind to these events and doing anything you want from there.

Comment: Take advantage of the native events whenever possible. +1

Comment: Does that HTML5 player use the same media events? If so, how would I go about binding these to jQuery's .on()? Sorry, I'm still trying to learn this all.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to get that working. I've updated my original post, am I doing this correctly. How would I also tell it when finished to animate again. I assume I use the "ended" media event?

Comment: So, while my code above works, it feels bloated. The slide animation is also quite jittery. Any way to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

Off the cuff you can use custom events to trigger the behavior.

for example:

```
$('body').bind('videoPlay', function() {
   // fancy animation stuff here..
   alert('video started playing');
});
```

and inside the o.play function you would add something like this:

```
$('body').trigger('videoPlay');
```

that is, of course, if you have access to the javascript and can modify it in the correct places..

===

another option is to overwrite o.play with your own method, and then call the original o.play.. I don't know if this will work however since it appears your example o.play() method handles both pause() and play()? something like this:

```
var oldplay = o.play;
o.play = function() {
  $('body').trigger('videoPlay');
  return oldplay.call();
}
```

In any case you can bind to custom events and react to them, as long as you know where you need to 'trigger' the events.